SMD soldering with hot air
I'm fairly new to SMD work but have worked for a very long time with more tradition soldering.
I've tried various ways to remove faulty SMDs (ICs usually) with my hot air gun but have a reoccurring problem of the PCB "popping" where the top layer of the board separates from the lower lifting all the tracks around the component i want to remove (before the solder has melted)
I've tried resoldering the component with a traditional iron and solder first, fluxing around it etc. I've tried all sorts of heat air settings
What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated, so far I'm working with scrap boards so no harm done :)

Consider looking at the datasheets of various components.  They usually have guidelines around temperatures.  Also, use a hot air gun that can be temperature controlled.  My first thought is that you are overheating the board.  You also should also consider warming the board and then reaching the desired temperature so that the solder melts.
This resistor datasheet is a good example:
https://docs.rs-online.com/7423/0900766b8157c91e.pdf
The soldering condition section demonstrates temperatures and times.

My guess is that your "hot air gun" is the usual hardware-store one designed for paint stripping, and is way too high temperature for soldering. Get a proper hot air station and things should work better.

If your board is delaminating you are getting it WAY too hot. Possibly damaging the parts as well.
Get a proper air de-soldering tool that has controlled temperature hot air, or at least a heat gun with a digital temperature setting in degrees and watch some videos on repairs involving SMT de-soldering.
Boards (especially those with internal power planes) may take some time to heat to a high enough temperature for the solder to melt, so patience..  Preheating the entire board to something around 100°C helps.


use plenty of flux. Flooding the IC with liquid flux is not a bad idea
use a temperature controlled hot air source with the nozzle some distance away from the PCB. I find about 1.5 inches works for QFN and QFP packages.
don't keep the hot air flowing continuously at a single point. Taking it in a continuous circle or quick but steady sweeps over rows of pins generally helps get all of the IC pins heated without overheating a particular point.
if the original solder is unleaded or old or both, which it likely is if the if the board was soldered commercially in the last decade or so, you may need to add some leaded solder to the pins to help get the melting started. Unleaded solder already melted can do the same thing, of course, but using leaded solder gives you a little bit more leeway in terms of how quickly you need to move your hands. Whether you're allowed to use leaded solder at all is something you'd have to work out.
If it's a BGA or any package with numerous pins underneath the package body, you may not be able to avoid having to preheat the PCB in the vicinity of the IC you wish to remove. Relatively small ones do still come off without preheat, though. Remember that the heat needs to flow through the IC body, so it will take time and you should generally be prepared to lose the IC itself.
have patience. Don't push the temperature or increase airflow, or try to focus the hot air on particularly difficult pins. Given time, most ICs will come off.
when possible, be aware of problem areas in the design. Pins connected directly to large planes, heatsinks, or other forms of bulk thermal mass will take a lot more time to get off. If you have many such pins, or a thermal pad under the IC which refuses to lift off, or for things like SMA RF connectors properly soldered on, you may want to try other approaches. If you can deliver extra heat to the pad through vias from the other side, that's worth a try. The best option is a full board preheat, though, if you can.



... with my hot air gun but have a reoccurring problem of the PCB "popping" where the top layer of the board separates from the lower lifting all the tracks around the component i want to remove (before the solder has melted)...
Any help would be much appreciated, so far I'm working with scrap boards so no harm done :)

Old scrap PCB boards can easily delaminate, even with a reasonable air temperature setting. Over time, the resin-based materials (such as epoxy) in the PCB absorb moisture from the air. When hot air is applied, the absorbed moisture undergoes thermal expansion. This expansion can create visible gaps or bubbles within the PCB, which are typically referred to as blisters. These blisters weaken the adhesive bonds between the layers (copper layers included), ultimately leading to delamination.
For practice, try using new PCB boards. Alternatively, you can purchase SMT soldering practice boards on AliExpress.


I'm not a fan of hot air - I know I'm in a minority. I find it hard to control where the air goes and the temperature that components reach. I prefer a good old fashioned soldering iron.
The first question is: what are you trying to save? The component or the PCB?
If you're trying to remove a dead chip and it has external legs (i.e. it's not a BGA or whatever) then run a fine knife along next to the chip body and cut all the pins. Remove the body. Using fine forceps and a fine soldering tip, remove each pin. Lots of flux helps. I've never damaged a PCB doing it that way. You're applying the heat to a small area in a very controlled way.
If you're trying to remove a SM resistor (etc.) then solder a short piece of tinned copper wire over the resistor so you've got a thermal connection to both pins. Heat the whole thing up and lift it off with forceps. That also works with transistors using a suitably bent piece of wire.
If you're trying to remove a good chip from a bad PCB then heat up the whole PCB from the underside. I put a piece of 2mm steel plate over a gas stove and put the PCB on that. Lift the components up with forceps. By heating under the board you're stressing the component less. The steel plate applies the heat evenly with less scorching. It produces LOTS of bad gasses so you need to do it outside. (Health and Safety? What's that?)
Of course, this is only worthwhile for a few chips at a hobbyist level. If it's a professional situation then what are you playing at? Just spend the money and start again with a new PCB and components.
